# How to retrieve the correct parent object based on the values from the nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
var items = [
  {
    itemId: 0,
    itemQuantity: 10,
    attributes: [
      { type: "Size", value: "Small" },
      { type: "Color", value: "Black" }
    ]
  },
  {
    itemId: 1,
    itemQuantity: 20,
    attributes: [
      { type: "Size", value: "Small" },
      { type: "Color", value: "White" }
    ]
  },
  {
    itemId: 2,
    itemQuantity: 30,
    attributes: [
      { type: "Size", value: "Medium" },
      { type: "Color", value: "Black" }
    ]
  },
  {
    itemId: 3,
    itemQuantity: 40,
    attributes: [
      { type: "Size", value: "Medium" },
      { type: "Color", value: "White" }
    ]
  }
];
```

I also have a basic array that contains the following values

```
let selectedAttributes = ["Small", "Black"];
```

My goal is to obtain the **parent** object based on the values from the nested array (`attributes`). To elaborate more, I need to check the values in the `selectedAttributes` array with the `value` property in the nested array (`attributes`). Which means that, I need to retrieve the object that contains **both** the values "Small" and "Black". This should be the result of it:

```
let result = [
  {
    itemId: 0,
    itemQuantity: 10,
    attributes: [
      { type: "Size", value: "Small" },
      { type: "Color", value: "Black" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Below is my current code. When I console the result, I got an empty array

```
let result = items.filter((item, index) => {
  return item.attributes.some(attri => attri.value === selectedAttributes);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, @CodeManiac I've made a slight edit to my post to clear some confusion. Basically, I want to retrieve the parent object that has the values "Black" and "Small" from its child array (attributes)

Comment: Use `every()` instead of `some()` if you want all to exist and not just some of them

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I got an empty array as a result. I've made a slight edit to my post and code to clear some confusion. Basically, I want to retrieve the parent object that has the values "Black" and "Small" from its child array (attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking the `value` of the first matched object (as you're using `.some`) and no other objects. Instead, you want to check if every `value` attribute for each object is an attribute in your attribute list by using `.includes`:

```js
const items = [ { itemId: 0, itemQuantity: 10, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Small" }, { type: "Color", value: "Black" }, ] }, { itemId: 1, itemQuantity: 20, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Small" }, { type: "Color", value: "White" } ] }, { itemId: 2, itemQuantity: 30, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Medium" }, { type: "Color", value: "Black" } ] }, { itemId: 3, itemQuantity: 40, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Medium" }, { type: "Color", value: "White" } ] } ];

const selectedAttributes = ["Small", "Black"];
const res = items.filter((item, index) => {
  return item.attributes.every(attri => selectedAttributes.includes(attri.value));
});

console.log(res);
```

If all you want is just the object (and not an arary of objects), you can use `.find()` instead of `filter()`. As `.find()` will stop once the inner function returns `true`:

```js
const items = [ { itemId: 0, itemQuantity: 10, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Small" }, { type: "Color", value: "Black" }, ] }, { itemId: 1, itemQuantity: 20, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Small" }, { type: "Color", value: "White" } ] }, { itemId: 2, itemQuantity: 30, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Medium" }, { type: "Color", value: "Black" } ] }, { itemId: 3, itemQuantity: 40, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Medium" }, { type: "Color", value: "White" } ] } ];

const selectedAttributes = ["Small", "Black"];
const res = items.find((item, index) => {
  return item.attributes.every(attri => selectedAttributes.includes(attri.value));
});

console.log(res);
```

---

Please note, the above solution will work if all attribute objects match the attributes in the list provided. If you want it such that the attributes in the object can have other attributes as well as those part of the attribute list, you'll need to use `.every` on your attribute list rather than your object attributes like so:

```js
const items = [ { itemId: 0, itemQuantity: 10, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Small" }, { type: "Color", value: "Black" }, ] }, { itemId: 1, itemQuantity: 20, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Small" }, { type: "Color", value: "White" } ] }, { itemId: 2, itemQuantity: 30, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Medium" }, { type: "Color", value: "Black" } ] }, { itemId: 3, itemQuantity: 40, attributes: [ { type: "Size", value: "Medium" }, { type: "Color", value: "White" } ] } ];

const attrs = ["Small", "Black"];
const res = items.filter((item, index) => {
 const values = item.attrs.map(o => o.value);
  return attrs.every(attri => values.includes(attri));
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi Nick I have one question, what is the use of the || logical operator?

Comment: @Issaki hi, that was my bad. It actually isn't needed

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply! Since the result only contains a single object in the array. Is it possible if you can remove the array and just display the object alone?